# Invisible Margin Between Td and Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This margin is not there in the inspect mode, but added automatically after I change the div size.I'm a little lost why is this happening

```
    var headerTd = $(headerTr.cells[i]);
    var dataTd = $(dataTr.cells[i ]);
    var commonWidth = Math.max(Math.min(headerTd.width(), 100), dataTd.width());
    headerTd.width('1%').find('> div').width(commonWidth);
      dataTd.children().first().width(commonWidth);
```

[image: ]]

Comment: There's more than HTML and CSS going on in your code example. Is that also javascript and jQuery? Something else?

Comment: What happens in this example is that the table cells have wider content than what would fit in `1%`, so the browser ignores the `1%` and displays the cells at the width of their contents. In the screenshot, this is 375px, so the div of 343px wide has some space to its right. Does that answer your question?